# Why is a shallow autoencoder outperforming deep neural nets on a tabular dataset?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, autoencoder, tabular

Just tried different denoising autoencoder architectures for a tabular dataset.

It seems that, for this table of size `N*d`, the best performance comes from a flat architecture with only one hidden layer (a.k.a. the bottleneck), of size larger than the number of input dimensions (num. of bottleneck neurons around `1.5*d`).

Wondering how to interpret this result, especially why is it that a shallow autoencoder outperforms deeper architectures... I guess it could be related to the Universal approximation theorem or to [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/182734/what-is-the-difference-between-a-neural-network-and-a-deep-neural-network-and-w), but can't really get a thorough understanding.

Comment: Perhaps it has to do with the complexity of the problem itself. And the shallow model may be better suited to this case.